# Any tool to convert Birt engine .rptdesign files to XSLT format

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, pdfbox, birt, apache-fop

Currently I am using Birt Report runtime version which takes .rptdesign files as a template and data from database to create/render dynamic pdfs. It also renders pdf on web browser.

I am looking for converting .rptdesign files to XSLT and use as input to Apache FOP product to generated pdf.

A) Could you please tell any existing tool or api which will help to convert .rptdesign files to XSLT ?
B) Can you please provide inputs about Apache FOP performance as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Such tools do not exist and probably will never exist.
The technologies are way too different.

Comment: I disagree.  An rptdesign file is simply an XML file. Creating an XSL to convert this to XSLT would be somewhat trivial.

Comment: We have done Adobe Lifecycle, we have done Word plugin, we started and might finish in browser summernote editor (HTML, CSS) to XSL (http://cloudformatter.com/Nimbus). All of these use XSL to convert some XML language to XSL.

Comment: Well, if you are working on a commercial product, good luck. I didn't say that it is impossible, it is just an enormous effort. Note that BIRT reports include JavaScript logic. It is not a big deal to convert the basic layout, but you'll also have to convert the data sets (e.g. SQL queries) and the scripts.